# How do I pass variables and/or functions from one php file to another?

Tags: php, scope

1.php:

```
$x = 10;
```

2.php:

```
echo $x;
```

Both these files are in the same directory. I want to be able to access `$x` in `2.php` but I haven't found a good way to do that other than defining another file where i initailize `$x` and then include it in both `1.php` and `2.php`. I don't want extra files to deal with in my project.

Edit: FYI, there might be code in `1.php` that I don't want executed in `2.php` so `include '1.php'` doesn't work for me

Comment: you can use the session to store value to use in the application pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use include file 1.php in 2.php or require

```
include '1.php';
```

Comment: But I might have other code in 1.php that I don't want executed in 2.php. Therefore, this does not work for me. Thanks though :)

Comment: You can define some const in `2.php`, then just wrap your `1.php` code that you don't want to execute in `2.php` with condition to check that const is not defined before executing.

Comment: Honestly this is never a good practice. The common practice is to have the common logics in the 3rd file (usually named `includes/common.php`) because you rarely know how many files are going to use it. An extra file is more predictable than a file thats both executable itself and as some common setup. Especially when you maintain it years later.